# Rails: How to get ajax to refresh index after edit/update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**CRUD** from Index page.

I know there are gems to make this easy, but would like to avoid if possible.

On Index.html.erb
- Rendering _newsfeeds partial into < ul id="feedsNews" > on index.html.erb
- partial form ( :Create and :Edit are using same form )
- When user clicks 'Edit' btn on newsfeed, I'm appending partial form to newsfeed

Problems
Edit/update changes are being made ...UNFORTUNATELY, I can't seem to get the ajax:success to reload the _newsfeeds partial on index.html.erb. If it's something silly, I apologize...

**NEWSFEEDS_CONTROLLER**

```
    def index
      @newsfeeds = Newsfeed.all
      @newsfeed = Newsfeed.new
      @newsfeeds = Newsfeed.order("position") #for Sortable

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @newsfeeds }
        format.js
      end
    end

    def update
      @newsfeed = Newsfeed.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @newsfeed.update_attributes(params[:newsfeed])
          format.html { redirect_to newsfeeds_url, notice: 'Updated' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @newsfeed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <div>
        <div id="spinner" style="display:none;"></div>
        <ul id="feedsNews" class="showList" data-update-url="<%= sort_newsfeeds_url %>" >
            <%= render :partial => @newsfeeds %>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
    $('#<%= dom_id(@newsfeed, :edit) %>')
        .bind('ajax:send', function(){
           $('#spinner').show();
        })
        .bind('ajax:success', function() {
           $('#spinner').hide();
           $('#feedsNews').innerHTML ('<%= escape_javascript(render(@newsfeeds)) %>')
        })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**----------------UPDATE--------------------**

Changed it to this, which works... sorta... the index.js.erb seems like it's firing before the redirect from the update action, so the firebug is giving me an endless 'spinner' for the index.js.erb GET request

```
    $.ajax({
    complete: function() {
    $('#feedsNews').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @newsfeeds) %>');
    alert('Changes Saved!');
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to let Rails do this kind of job(refresh partial by ajax). Because you have to write both Ruby and js code.

This job should be done by jQuery only. e.g. send ajax request and then call the `update action` in a callback, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the following, but the js appears to fire before the redirect from the update action, which is odd. Will let you know if I figure out what's going on        ' $.ajax({
 complete: function() {
  $('#feedsNews').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @newsfeeds) %>');
  alert('Changes Saved!');
 }
}); '